# Laravel - How to filter by Dropdown in DB Raw

Tags: laravel

I have this model class:

```
class Billings extends Model
{
protected $table = 'billings';

protected $fillable = [
    'msisdn',
    'created_at',
    'amount',
    'billing_channel',   
];


protected $guarded = [
    'id'
];
}
```

Controller

```
    public function billingsReport(Request $request)
{        
    $billings = DB::table('billings')
    ->select(
       'msisdn', 
         DB::raw('created_at as created_date'),
       'amount',
       'billing_channel'
  )               
 ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC');         

    $render=[];       
    if(isset($request->msisdn))
    {
        $billings=$billings->where('msisdn','like','%'.$request->msisdn.'%');
        $render['msisdn']=$request->msisdn;
    }   
    if(isset($request->billing_channel))
    {
        $billings=$billings->where('billing_channel','like','%'.$request->billing_channel.'%');
        $render['billing_channel']=$request->billing_channel;
    }               
    $billings= $billings->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    $billings= $billings->paginate(15);
    $billings= $billings->appends($render);
    $data['billings'] = $billings;

return view('report.billingsReport',$data);        
}
```

Note that the field billing_channel is in billings table

View

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    {{ Form::model(request(),['method'=>'get']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-2">
         {{ Form::text('msisdn',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'MSISDN']) }}
    </div>         
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

Already the text filter for msisdn is working.

From my controller and view, I filter the msisdn and also use **form::text** in the view. The issue now is, how do I also filter billing_channel using **form::select**

How do I modify my model, view and controller to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Get an iterable set of billingChannels and pass them to the view.

Then you could add something like this to the form:

```php
<select name="billing_channel">
@foreach($billingChannel as $billingChannel)
    <option value={{ $billingChannel->value }}>{{ $billingChannel->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

You appear to already have the code in your controller so this should be all you'll need.

If you wanted to use the `Form` facade from Laravel Collective, take a look at their [documentation](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.6/html.md#generating-a-grouped-list) to get an idea of how to use it.

Answer (score -2):

Your model is correct but for the controller I will recommend you to use the model to get the data, also for the frontend you can use `select2` https://select2.github.io/select2/ to show and it fill help you to filter it from the select, its pretty easy to use, for the controller you can use something like:

```
public function billingsReport(Request $request)
{
        $msisdn = $request->msisdn;

        $billings = Billings::select('msisdn', 'created_at as created_date', 'amount', 'billing_channel')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->when(isset($request->msisdn), function($query) use ($msisdn) {
                $query->where('msisdn','like','%'.$msisdn.'%');
            })
            ->paginate(15);


        return view('report.billingsReport', compact('billings'));        
}
```

and for the view you use:

```
<select class="form-control" id="yourid">
@foreach($billings as $billing)
<option value="{{ your key }}">{{ the filed that you want to display }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Laravel 5.8 version

Comment: @JavierEmmanuelMercedes. Its like you dont understand me. I have done the filter for msisdn as text filter. Now I want to add another filter for billing_channel, but it should be a dropdown. And I dont know how to add this to my code. Also I want to stick to Form::   that am using in the view